# safari extension with two connected toolbar items

Tags: safari-extension

Is there a way to make a Safari Extension, which has two toolbar buttons, connected, like safari's back and forward buttons?

Can't seem to find information about this anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a button that is similar to the arrows, with three states?  non-pressed, left pressed and right pressed and then program the two states that you need to execute?

Comment: interesting. i could, but i really want to have both the buttons, as i think it lends to less confusion. how did you know this safari extension had arrows? ;)